# Calculate how much bits is in int without sizeof()

Tags: c, int, bit, unsigned-integer

i am trying to create simple game. Task is to create program that calculate size of int in bites.
Their code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int intSize(void)
{
    unsigned int x,
        i = 0;
        x = ?;
    while ((?) != 0)
        ?;
    return ?;
}
int main()
{
    printf("Size is %d bits\n",?);
    return 0;
}
```

? is place where i should put my code.

This is what one of my tries

```
#include <stdio.h>
int intSize(void)
{
    unsigned int x,
        i = 0;
        x = 0;
    while ((x>>1) != 0)
        i++;
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    printf("Size ise %d bits\n", intSize());
    return 0;
}
```

I know that usigned int is 4bytes so i use bitwise operation to move bits it should be 32 but i am getting 1. I will be thankfull for any help.

Comment: initializing *x* with 0 the `while ((x>>1) != 0)` if immediately false, the right value is -1, and yu missed the () in the call of the function

Comment: Yes thanks, that was one problem I forgot to call function. FIXED. But with value 1 or -1 i am still  getting just one as result.

Comment: The problem statement is defective, and this should be reported to the teacher who assigned the problem. The template code uses `unsigned`, but counting the number of bits used to represent values in `unsigned` is not guaranteed to produce a correct result for `int` because the C standard does not require `int` to use the same number of bits as `unsigned`; there may be padding bits. If `<limits.h>` were included, `x` could be initialized to `INT_MAX`, and then the number of bits could be counted. Otherwise, there is no way to probe the width of an `int` in a defined way, due to overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having

```
x = 0;
while ((x>>1) != 0)
  ...
```

the *while* stops immediately, so *i* is unchanged and the return value is 0.

The right way was to initialize *x* with`~0u` to have all bits valuing 1 (suppose 2-complements)

Out of that the test is not the right one and you missed to modify the value of *x*.

In

> ```
> printf("Size ise %d bits\n", intSize);
> ```

you missed the *()* to call the function, currently you try to write its address, I say try because an address must be `printf` with the format `%p`.

Finally:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int intSize(void)
{
  unsigned int x,
     i = 0;

  x = ~0u;
  while ((x & 1) != 0)
    (i+= 1, x /= 2); /* not x >= 1 in case it is a rotate rather than a shift */
  return (int) i;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Size is %d bits\n", intSize());
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Size is 32 bits
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

So in order the '?' are :

- `~0u`
- `x & 1`
- `(i+= 1, x /= 2)`
- `(int) i`

Comment: Dont know why but result is 0.

Comment: @JurajJakubov you have 0 if you call the function but have the rest unchanged, as I say in my answer the `while` is never executed, so *i* values 0

Comment: But i can change only places where is "?" i cant totally remade while condition.

Comment: @JurajJakubov I edited, so I use the artificial but working form `(i+= 1, x /= 2)` for the ? as the body of the `while`

Comment: Well you answer is really good. And I am thankful for your time But there were things we cannot change. But is solved now.

Comment: Thanks you thats what i was looking :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect because it determines the number of bits in an `unsigned int`, but the C standard does not require an `int` to use the same number of bits to represent values; it may have padding bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the name of the function can be wrong, anyway the template is imposed, only ? can be replaced, I preferred to not cast everywhere. If you look at my remark on the question I said `the right value is -1` for *x* so for an *int* rather than an *unsigned*, then I supposed the function wrongly named

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this problem by putting a 1 in the low bit of an integer and shift **left** until it's zero, which means the bit clocked all the way out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int intSize(void)
{
    unsigned int x,
        i = 0;
        x = 1;
    while ((x <<= 1) != 0)
        i++;
    return i+1;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Size is %d bits\n", /*?*/ intSize());
    return 0;
}
```

No concerns about signed/unsigned as far as I can tell.

**EDIT** to reflect the ? placeholder requirements of the project.

Comment: Thanks for demo. But i can only change places where is "?".

Comment: Edited to reflect that.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT34-C.+Do+not+shift+an+expression+by+a+negative+number+of+bits+or+by+greater+than+or+equal+to+the+number+of+bits+that+exist+in+the+operand

Comment: This isn't undefined behavior. He shifts by `1` bit. `1` is way lower then number of bits in `int`.

Comment: @KamilCuk you mean `INT_MAX << 1` is not UB?

Comment: If an int is 32 bits, then `x <<= 33` would be undefined behavior.

Comment: @KamilCuk I thought that overflow on signed types was UB. Then `int x = INT_MAX << 1;` doesn't overflow?

Comment: @KamilCuk: The behavior of `INT_MAX << 1` is not defined by the C standard per C 2018 6.5.7 4, “The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1` × 2\*\*`E2`, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1` × 2\*\*`E2` is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: @KamilCuk the answer was edited, it was a `signed int`